# Null value for anonymous types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a routine in C# where I pull a list of objects as such:

```
var data = sdfController.GetFundingSummary(CurrentUser.UserId, _companyId, "category");
```

Once I have that data, I need to derive a list of names from it, which I'm doing thusly:

```
var fundingNames = 
                (from names in data.AsEnumerable() 
                 where names.FundingYear.Equals(_year.ToString())
                 select new  { FundingName = names.FundingName }).Distinct().ToList();
```

and then I'm binding that list to a listview:

```
lvSDF.DataSource = fundingNames;
lvSDF.DataBind();
```

It all works great if there's data, blows up if there isn't any.  I have emptyDataTemplates in place on the .aspx side to display a message if there aren't any records but I can't figure out how to initialize fundingNames to null.

Comment: Define 'blowing up'. What error are you getting? What  does `GetFundingSummary` return when there is no data matching the criteria?`null` or an empty enumeration? What is `data`s type? What is `_year` and can it be `null`? Etc. You need to provide more information.

Comment: Yes, sorry, GetFundingSummary is returning null.  And when I try to pull the funding names, it throws "{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}.

Comment: Just check if `data` is null, and act accordingly.

Comment: Unless your computer *actually* blows up, "blowing up" is not a good problem description. Please describe the actual problem you're having without metaphors.

Comment: Did you write `GetFundingSummary`? Do not return `null` from functions; if having no objects is an abnormal situation, throw an exception. If it is not an abnormal situation, return a collection with zero items; this simplifies your code considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `data` can be `null`.

You need to check if this is the case before creating the LINQ query:

```
var fundingNames = data = null ? ...your query... : new List<string>();
```

Im guessing `FundingName` is a `string` here. Change accordingly if not. Also if that's the case, why are you creating an anonymous type with `new { ... }`? Return the string directly:

```
from ...
select names.FundingNames;
```

As PaulF correctly points out you need to do this or you'll probably get a conversion error between `List<string>` and `List<AnonymousTypeContainingOnlyOneString>`.

Comment: Doesn't the _select new  { FundingName = names.FundingName })._ create an instance of an anonymous type - hence the required use of var.

Comment: It is a string.  So trying this:

                    var fundingNames = data != null ? (from names in data.AsEnumerable() where names.FundingYear.Equals(_year.ToString())
                        select new  { FundingName = names.FundingName }).Distinct().ToList() : Enumerable.Empty<string>();

I get a design time error that I can'd do an implicit conversion between a generic list and a generic Ienumerable.

Comment: @PaulF True, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Just wondering if your modified solution will fail for the ListView Trevor is trying to bind to, as there will be no FundingNames property - it is just a string list. I don't know if this will solve the problem _var fundingNames = (data == null) ? ...your original query... : null;_That should compile & initialise fundingNames to null if data is null.

Comment: @PualF Do you need to bind to a property name when it's simply a list of strings? I thought you didn't have to but its ages since I've programmed anything remotely similar so I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure on that either - but if the ListView already is bound to a FundingName property, I would at least expect it to need to be removed - though I could be wrong, which is why I started with "Just wondering if...". If there is an issue, at least the comment may point Trevor in the right direction for fixing it.